# Upload/Put file Directly in FTP server while user will upload in webpage form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, ftp

I would like to know that is there any possibility that whatever (JPG, JPEG, PDF, Zip etc..) file will be uploaded by the user in webpage form control that will directly upload/Put on the FTP server without storing first temporary in website server and then transfer in FTP server ?

Actually i have a business case that user can able to upload more then 200 MB of file so here i would like to directly transfer it in Remote FTP server without storing it in website server.

further i have investigated that html form tag allow the FTP protocol in Action attribute and below are the code snipped which i have tried.

```
<form action="ftp://username:password@domainname/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" width="500px">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td> Upload File :</td>
            <td> <input name="uploadedfile" type="file"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
             <input name="Save File" value="Save File on Server" type="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>     
    </tbody></table>
</form>
```

But when i am trying to upload the image and submit it then it redirect me into the ftp://username:password@domainname/upload.php url in browser and that will display the PHP code which i have scripted inside the upload.php file.

Actually I already aware that how to transfer the file in Remote FTP server once the form submit and transfer the file from server temporary location ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']) to FTP server but by doing this way it will take double time as first the file getting uploaded in website server and then further transfer in Remote FTP server.

You can also suggest me the alternative way to achieve my business need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ftp_put(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Here's what your start of a .php file might look like:

```
<?PHP
   $myFile = $_FILES['file_name']; // This will make an array out of the file information that was stored.
?>
```

Now when it comes to transmitting that information...

```
<?PHP
        $destination_path = "src/bin/";
```

//where you want to throw the file on the webserver (relative to your login dir)

```
$destination_file = $destination_path."img.jpg";
```

//This will create a full path with the file on the end for you to  use,  like splitting the variables like this in case I need to use on on their own or if dynamically creating new folders.

```
$file = $myFile['tmp_name'];
```

//Converts the array into a new string containing the path name on the server where your file is.

```
    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $file, FTP_BINARY);// upload the file
    if (!$upload) {// check upload status
        echo "FTP upload of $destination_file has failed!";
    } else {
        echo "Uploaded $file to $conn_id as $destination_file";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But actually i want to transfer the file without storing in website server. in your mentioned code, first the user uploaded file getting stored in server under /tmp location of the server and then it further transfer to Remote FTP

Comment: You can make use of PHP PUT Method. PHP provides support for the HTTP PUT method used by some clients to store files on a server.  http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: Hello Santosh, thanks for your response as your response give me alternative way to achieve my need. But here i am not sure how can i use HTTP put method means suppose in my form there are so many controls along with file control then how can fetch the file control only out of all form elements ?

Comment: @SantoshJagtap From the perspective of the question, there's no difference between `POST` and `PUT`. In both cases the file gets uploaded to the web server first. And implementing `PUT` is more difficult than `POST` (which is natively supported by the HTML).